# How to prove Detailed Balance Condition?

Tags: markov-chains

Given a Markov chain with a stationary distribution $\mathbf{\pi}$ and a transition matrix P, it satisfies the Detailed Balance Condition if:

$$
\pi_i P_{ij}= \pi_j P_{ji}, \quad \forall i,j
$$

**My question is, how to derive this equation?**

---

I have tried the 2-dimensional version:

Given:
$$
\pi=[\pi_1,\pi_2]
$$

$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} \\ 
p_{21} & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

When stationary:

$$
\pi P = \pi
$$

Then:

$$
\pi_1 P_{11} +\pi P_{21} =\pi_1 \\
\pi_1 P_{12} +\pi P_{22} =\pi_2
$$

The two equaitons can be simplified to the same equation:

$$
\pi_1 P_{12} =\pi_2 P_{21}
$$

And this conforms to the Detailed Balance Equation.

But how to prove the 3-dimensional version and the general n-dimensional version?

Comment: From Wikipedia:"The detailed balance condition is stronger than that required merely for a stationary distribution; that is, there are Markov processes with stationary distributions that do not have detailed balance.".

Comment: I don't understand.  This seems to be a definition (for the "detailed balance condition"), not a theorem.  What are you trying to prove?